# Can XPath group a selected node list by intermediate nodes?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
  <b>
    <c>r</c>
    <c>s</c>
    <c>t</c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>u</c>
    <c>v</c>
    <c>w</c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>x</c>
    <c>y</c>
    <c>z</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

With an XPath query of "a/b/c/text()" I can extract a list easily:

```
[ r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z ]
```

Is it possible to get the result grouped by the level 'b' like this:

```
[
  [ r, s, t ],
  [ u, v, w ],
  [ x, y, z ] 
]
```

[fiddle](http://xpather.com/xxauJ6Tk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, XPath alone cannot produce a list of lists of strings:

- XPath 1.0's nodesets are never nested.
- XPath 2.0/3.1's sequences are never nested.

In general, XPath is for *selection*, not transformation.  In your first example, XPath selects a list of text nodes and presents them as a list of string values.

To further *transform* the nodes selected by one or more XPath expressions, employ the general programming facilities of the hosting language (XSLT, Python, JavaScript, etc).

---

**Update:** Per your comment, you indicate that a lexical representation of the desired grouping would suffice.  Yes, you *could* compose the targeted output via string functions:

### XPath 2.0

```
concat('[', 
       string-join(for $b in /a/b
                       return concat('[',string-join($b/c,','),']'),
                   ','),
       ']')
```

Comment: There is no transformation. The nesting is present in the XML document.

Comment: There are nested elements, but the nesting of lists you seek does not exist as part of the output model of XPath, thus the need to transform that which you select into the output form you desire.

Comment: Found a solution (with *string-join()*).

Comment: If a lexical representation of nesting is all you need, yes, you can use XPath's string functions.